# How to interpret and use a class given an interface object?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, reflection

I have an interface. One of my methods takes as argument an object of this interface. Depending on the concrete class, I want to build a different object.

```
public interface Shape {
  public void draw();
}

public class Circle implements Shape {
  private int radius;
  //constructor etc.

  public void draw() {
    System.out.println("CIRCLE!");
  }

  public int getRadius() {
    return radius;
  }
}

public class Square implements Shape {
  private int side;

  //constructor etc.

  public void draw() {
    System.out.println("SQUARE!");
  }

  public int getSide() {
    return side;
  }
}


public class MyClass {
  public void myJob(Shape shape) {
    if (shape.getClass().toString().equals("Circle")) {
      // some missing code...what to do here? type cast? transform?
      int radius = shape.getRadius();
    }
  }
}
```

How do I take the `Shape` interface and then get the `radius` or `side` out of it depending on the type of class?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You should look into using polymorphism to solve your issue instead of trying to cast to either a Circle or Square.

Comment: So, you want to deal with an interface rather than a concrete class to abstract away any implementation details and then, when you actually get a hold of such interface, you insist on knowing exactly what kind of object you are dealing with so you can call some method the interface does not offer. This is utterly pointless. You would be better off with multiple myJob methods, each taking a different type (circle, square, et cetera).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no need to use reflection for this, you can use the keyword `instanceof`

```
public void myJob(Shape shape) {
    if (shape instanceof Circle) {
        // some missing code...what to do here? type cast? transform?
        int radius = shape.getRadius();
    }
}
```

Then, what you want to do is to cast your shape into a circle, so you can treat it like a circle:

```
public void myJob(Shape shape) {
    if (shape instanceof Circle) {
        Circle circle = (Circle) shape;
        // Some Circle job
        int radius = circle.getRadius();
    }
}
```

Finally, if as you said you want to apply different treatments to different implementations of Shape, you can explicitly type the parameter:

```
public void myJob(Circle circle) {
    // Some Circle job
}

public void myJob(Square square) {
    // Some Square job
}
```

However, a better way to do that would be to use the Shape interface:

```
public interface Shape {
    void draw();
    void myJob();
}

public class MyClass {
    public void myJob(Shape shape) {
        shape.myJob();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Having instance of operator to fix broken abstraction is not a good answer.

Comment: I ended up including the myJob() in my Shape itself. since `shape` will always invoke the right method.

Answer (score 2):

All of the code that is `Shape` specific should be located in the methods overridden by each subclass.

```
public interface Shape {
    public void draw();
    public int getMeasure();
}

public class Circle implements Shape { ... } // The code for the methods in Shape should be written here.

public class Square implements Shape { ... }

public class MyClass {
    public void doWork(Shape shape) {
        int measure = shape.getMeasure();
    }
}
```

Typically, looking up the class by name at runtime is an unnecessary hassle that can be avoided.

**Edited for the question.**

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it's an instance of Circle by using instanceof and then cast it to a Circle if so.

```
if (shape instanceof Circle) {
  Circle circle = (Circle)shape;
  int radius = circle.getRadius();
}
```